# JavaScript/jQuery adding anchor tag inside a script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

enter image description hereI am new to php and JavaScript/jQuery. Before starting to Learn php I somehow know a little bit of htmL and css.

I have been editing a template I just downloaded and tumbled to this problem that I have been trying to figure out to look for a workaround

My problem is I can't make the result from my searchbox redirect to my update.php page on click of the result and clear the search when no match is found, and that is the output I am trying to accomplish.

I just can't make the same action from the anchor of my table when the user clicks the name do the same with my search bar.

I hope someone can help me.

(by the way, I am a magnifier and screen reader user due to some visual disability.)

Thanks in advance :-)

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ajax_crud");

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
$search_string = "SELECT * FROM name WHERE name LIKE ?";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

    $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';

    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

echo "<p>" . $row["name"] . "</p>";
            }
        } else{

echo "<p>No matches found!</p>";    

        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . 
mysqli_error($link);
    }
}

 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>

/* and the script

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){

    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(inputVal.length){
        $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){

          resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
    } else{
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }enter image description here
});

$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
$(this).parents(".search- 
box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
$(this).parent(".result").empty();
});
});
</script>


/* the part of the table where I can redirect the user to the update.php 
fiLe

echo sprintf('<td><a href="update.php?id=%s">%s</a></td>', $row['id'], 
$row['name']);
```

[this is how my index page Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGvpf.png)

[this is an exampLe of a search in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpAEJ.png)

[i cLicked on a resuLt from the search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7rpn.png)

[the resuLt is pLaced in the searchbox on cLick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSw0C.png)

[this is the update.php wherein the user shouLd be redirected upon cLicking the resuLt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW6GF.png)

i am sorry i wasn't abLe to add these Line of codes earLier.
i hope this couLd cLear things and make myseLf more understandabLe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(inputVal.length){
$.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
    resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
    } else{
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }
});

$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
$(this).parent(".result").empty();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. I was trying to understand the shape of your HTML from what you have given and figured your have a text field to search and when the user types something, you are getting the results from a PHP script and populate the `.result` drop down. Can you add the HTML of the page where the `.result` is and the output of the `backend-search.php` (it should be a collection of `<option>` tags). Also I'm not sure what you mean by _result from my searchbox redirect to my update.php page_ Please provide more information (more code, screenshots, etc..)

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is to redirect the user to the update.php page with the corresponding resuLt from the search box Like on the image..

i commented the code in which the user can be redirected to update.php page by cLicking the name from the tabLe
(ie.  echo sprintf('<td><a href="update.php?id=%s">%s</a></td>', $row['id'], $row['name']); )

my probLem is that i couLdn't figure out how to put the same anchor tag within my jquery script when i cLick on the resuLt from the search, instead the resuLt wiLL just be in the searchbox..

(i am trying to add the photos)

Comment: i just added photos with regards to my question..

Answer (score 0):

So you have an auto complete searchbox, and the results should not auto-complete the searchbox, but instead redirect to some other page?

If so, then you have a problem, the default jquery auto complete won't help you here, so your function to add contents to result should be custom and then insert html to an object you provide styling to yourself.

something like this:

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){

    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = document.getElementById("result");
    if(inputVal.length){
        //$.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
          // exmaple data response
          var data = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" onclick="console.log(\'option 1 got clicked\'); return true">name1</a><br><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924046/javascript-jquery-adding-anchor-tag-inside-a-script/51927190#51927190" target="_blank" onclick="console.log(\'option 2 got clicked\'); return true">name2</a>';
          resultDropdown.innerHTML = data;
    } else{
        resultDropdown.innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text">
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: no that's not what i mean, not the autocompLete but the transfer to the page update.php by cLicking on the resuLt feed by the searchbox..

i think i have to repLace this part:

 $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
 $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
 $(this).parent(".result").empty();

Comment: Is that not exacly what I did in the code snippet? Clicking on the custom auto-complete is now a simple anchor. Since it would be required to redirect, it is no longer of use to set the value to the searchbox, but as you can see, each anchor has it's own onclick, so you could do whatever you want.

Comment: i just added the script that i have been using for this one..
pLease see the updated post..

Comment: no jonathan, not the answer i was Looking for..
thank you for the answer anyway..

Comment: by the way, i am using ajax to feed the user every possibLe resuLt for each key input..

Comment: I get that, that is why I had set the data below the response from backend-search.php. If you make that script (backend-search.php) return the html with the simple anchor tags, you could do your redirects from the auto-complete list. Just a costom auto-complete list. As the default will only have a name, no id/url to redirect to. And the default action is not to redirect but put the text into the searchbox. If this is not what you want then please clarify what it is that you do want.